# Why does past participle following a reflexive verb agree?

Tags: participe-passé

In the sentence "La nuit d'Halloween, la ville de Darktown se retrouve envahie par les zombies", why does envahie agree in gender with la ville?

Comment: Given that the previous comments were based on my faulty analysis of the grammar, I've archived them in [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128029/discussion-on-question-by-ncardot-why-does-past-participle-following-a-reflexive) and reopened the question for discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Past participles of reflexive verbs can agree either with the subject or with the object. But the sentence in your question is in the present tense and the fact that it is a reflexive verb is irrelevant here.

*Se (re)trouver* is what we call a [stative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb)<sup>1</sup>. Stative verbs express a state or manner of being, they have no objects (direct or indirect) but are usually accompanied by a predicate that often is an adjective. This adjective agrees with the subject of the verb, just as with *être* (which is a stative verb), grammatically you can always replace any static verb with *être*.

In your sentence, since there is an agent, *les zombies*, we can say that *se retrouve envahie* is a passive voice and *envahie* is the past participle. Whether adjective or past participle, the word agrees with the subject.

- La ville se retrouve envahie/silencieuse...
- La ville semble envahie/silencieuse...
- La ville est envahie/silencieuse...
- La ville s'est retrouvée/se retrouvera/sera envahie ...

Answer (score -1):

C'est **la** **ville** qui *est* envahie.

Et comme c'est le verbe "*être*", on **accorde**.